# Django Forms ignoring USE_L10N configuration

Tags: python, django, django-forms, locale

It looks like my django application is not respecting the settings configuration `USE_L10N=True`

```
In [1]: from django import forms

In [2]: class SomeForm(forms.Form):
   ...:     some_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
   ...:

In [3]: form = SomeForm(data=dict(some_date='28/05/2020')); form.errors
Out[3]: {'some_date': ['Enter a valid date.']}

In [4]: from django.conf import settings

In [5]: settings.USE_L10N
Out[5]: True

In [6]: import locale

In [7]: locale.getlocale()
Out[7]: ('pt_BR', 'UTF-8')

In [8]: form = SomeForm(data=dict(some_date='05/28/2020')); form.errors
Out[8]: {}
```

If I use MM/DD/YYYY or YYYY/MM/DD it works. Shouldn't django be [using this pt-BR format](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/pt_BR/formats.py) instead?

What can be wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you set `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` to?

Comment: 'en-us' . Is this the reason?

Comment: Try changing it

Comment: Nope... I set it to `pt-br`, closed the `shell` session and entered again, checked the the `LANGUAGE_CODE` and it was `pt-br` and still not working, using the same example.

Comment: Tried some variations using `pt_BR` and I checked and I already have: `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'pt_BR'` and `LANGUAGES = [('pt_BR', gettext_lazy('Brazilian Portuguese')),]` set